# UnauthorizedAccessException when Creating file

Tags: c#

I have this code that downloads file from ftp server and then it creates that file in path that is set.

```
  string inputfilepath = @"C:\Users\me\Documents\Test";
        string ftphost = "ftp_server";
        string ftpfilepath = @"/TestDOTNET/text.TXT";

        string ftpfullpath = "ftp://" + ftphost + ftpfilepath;

        using (WebClient request = new WebClient())
        {
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
            byte[] fileData = request.DownloadData(ftpfullpath);

            File.SetAttributes(inputfilepath, FileAttributes.Normal);  

            using (FileStream file = File.Create(inputfilepath)) // this is the line where I get the exception
            {
                file.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
                file.Close();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Download Complete");

        }
```

I tried to create app.manifest and set requestedExcetuion level to `requireAdministrator` but still got no change.

Thank you for your time

Comment: I think your "inputfilepath" is a directory which is obviously read-only.

Comment: @Abhineet you are so right! I unet in the properties of the folder read-only but when I close and reopen the properties window it is still read-only. How can I unset that?

Comment: Programmatically or manually?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter, but programmatically it would be better.

Comment: var di = new DirectoryInfo("inputfilepath ");
di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

Comment: @Abhineet I tried to execute this code before doing the create but still got the sam ex.

Comment: How can you do it before creating the folder or file itself?

Comment: Also, you would like to do "file.Write" on some "file" and not on "folder" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first test for the Directory Path if it exists or not, if yes, then negate the `read-only` attribute for that directory. If not, then create directory and then create the `test.txt` to write in it.
Ex::

```
string inputdirpath = @"C:\Users\me\Documents\Test";
string inputfilepath = inputdirpath + "\text.TXT";

 // Downloading Stuff
 if(Directory.Exists(inputdirpath )) 
 {
    var di = new DirectoryInfo("inputfilepath "); 
    di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

    using (FileStream file = File.Create(inputfilepath)) 
            {
                file.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
                file.Close();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Download Complete");
 }
else
{
  // Create Directory
  // Set Attributes
  // Create file
  // Write data
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the user running the app has write-access to the file system?

Comment: I think this should be mentioned as comment but. In the folder I can create, edit, copy whatever I want. I think I got all rights to write to this folder.

Answer (score 2):

You should check that the effective user running the app - which is usually a different user (eg. NETWORK SERVICE user) from yourself - has the appropriate rights.

- Check on IIS application pool settings which is the user running the app
- Assign appropriate rights to such user on your target folder